# Woocommerce Image Categorie Page

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

English
How to avoid that in a page of categories woocommerce does not show the miniature of category or subcategory defined in "products / categories / add image" and to be able to place instead another image to discretion and conditioned to each name or Id of the category?

--

Español
Cómo evitar que en una página de categorías woocommerce no muestre la miniatura de categoria o subcategoria definida en "productos/categorias/add image" y poder colocar en cambio otra imagen a discreción y condicionada a cada nombre o Id de la categoría?

Thanks!
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Putting the question is two language sees to be unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry, my english es very bad! Sorry